# What's the difference between ConcurrentHashMap and Collections.synchronizedMap(Map) in term of performance?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to evaluate those concepts by using code. This is what I ended up with

```
    public void runCWith3Threads() {

        // mesure add with 3 threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Map<Integer, Person> shm = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Integer, Person>());
            Map<Integer, Person> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person>();

            MapThread sm1 = new MapThread(shm, 0, 20000, "sm1");
            MapThread sm2 = new MapThread(shm, 20000, 30000, "sm2");
            MapThread sm3 = new MapThread(shm, 30000, 50000, "sm3");

            sm1.start();sm2.start();sm3.start();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    sm1.join();
                    sm2.join();
                    sm3.join();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            long secondMax = sm1.time > sm2.time ? sm1.time : sm2.time;
            long firstMax = secondMax > sm3.time ? secondMax : sm3.time;

            System.out.println("Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: " + firstMax);

            MapThread m1 = new MapThread(chm, 0, 20000, "m1");
            MapThread m2 = new MapThread(chm, 20000, 30000, "m2");
            MapThread m3 = new MapThread(chm, 30000, 50000, "m3");

            m1.start();m2.start();m3.start();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    m1.join();
                    m2.join();
                    m3.join();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            secondMax = m1.time > m2.time ? m1.time : m2.time;
            firstMax = secondMax > m3.time ? secondMax : m3.time;

            System.out.println("Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: " + firstMax);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public class MapThread extends Thread {
        Map<Integer, Person> map;
        int from;
        int to;
        long time;
        String name;

        public MapThread(Map<Integer, Person> map, int from, int to, String name) {
            this.map = map;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void run() {

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
                map.put(i, new Person());
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time = end - start;
            return;
        }
    }
```

What I expect is, after the code runs, the `ConcurrentHashMap` 's result will be faster, since it allows multiple insertion into the map. For the `SynchronizedMap`, since each thread is waiting for the previous thread to finish (map is synchronized), the code will acts as the same once running with a single thread environment

However, the result is not completely reflect what I expected

```
Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 250
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 203

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 171
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 172

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 172
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 188

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 171
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 172

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 187
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 172

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 171
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 189

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 187
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 171

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 188
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 171

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 172
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 172

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 171
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 188
```

Why is that ?

**Update**

1. With

`Map<Integer, Person> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person>(100000, 10, 3);`

I have result

```
Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 208
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 216

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 255
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 196
```

1. With

`Map<Integer, Person> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person>(100000);`

I have result

```
Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 204
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 283

Millisec of SynchronizedMap cost: 203
Millisec of ConcurrentHashMap cost: 200
```

Comment: This question is answered in the [Javadoc for ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: I don't think you mean this ... `for (int i = from; i < to; i++) { map.put(from, new Person()); }`

Comment: no, @StephenC, i don't mean it. It is a typo mistake :(

Comment: Doesn't it change the results???

Comment: @StephenC  from the doc: `Because placement in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary.` Nope, that is not the root cause. I still figure out how to make it work

Comment: Ermm ... if you are only inserting 3 different keys (due to your bug), and each thread is inserting the same key over and over, then you'd expect the contention to be different when the bug was fixed.

Comment: @EJP I changed `concurrencyLevel` to several values like `Map<Integer, Person> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person>(3);`; does not work either :(

Comment: You are creating maps with the default initial size (which is 16 according to the javadocs), but you're adding 50,000 keys to each map. That means that the time spent resizing the map is likely to be dominating your timing results. Try it with an initial capacity of, say, 100,000 and see if that changes things.

Comment: @CameronSkinner please see my updated detail

Comment: 3 threads won't give you any noticeable difference in timings, try with more threads (10, 20 ...), also use `System.nanoTime`

Comment: Apart from the fact you need more Threads to detect a difference, also note that the performance improvements from `ConcurrentHashMap` are AFAIK more in access to the map (`get`), than in adding things to the map (`put`).

Comment: @bubuzzz Why are you addressing that comment to me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing benchmarks, you should:

1. doing a warm-up phase (due to JIT compilation and class loading),
2. repeat the test several times (due to garbage collection).

If I create such a benchmark that is similar to your benchmark, I get the following results:

```
Warmup...
Benchmark...
 4 *  500000: 0.22s / 0.04s
 4 * 1000000: 0.55s / 0.10s
 4 * 1500000: 1.10s / 0.16s
 4 * 2000000: 0.90s / 0.19s
 4 * 2500000: 1.68s / 0.25s
```

The first number shows the number of threads, the second number the size of the int ranges, the third number is the duration for a *synchronized Map* and the fourth number the duration for *ConcurrentHashMap*. As you can see, the *ConcurrentHashMap* is in all cases significantly faster.

Below you can find the whole Java code. Note that is makes use of features from Java 8. However, that should have no impact on the results:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("Warmup...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        test(Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>()), 2, 1000);
        test(new ConcurrentHashMap<>(), 2, 1000);
    }
    System.out.println("Benchmark...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        int threads = 4;
        int range = 500000 * (i + 1);
        System.out.printf("%2d * %7d: %s / %s\n",
            threads, range,
            test(Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>()), threads, range),
            test(new ConcurrentHashMap<>(), threads, range));
    }
}
public static String test(Map<Integer,Object> map, int threads, int range) {
    long duration = IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToLong(i -> execute(
                IntStream.range(0, threads)
                .<Runnable>mapToObj(t -> () -> bulkPut(map, t * range, (t + 1) * range, new Object()))
                .toArray(Runnable[]::new)))
        .min().getAsLong();
    return String.format("%4.2fs",
        duration / 1000.0, threads, range);
}
public static <T> void bulkPut(Map<Integer,T> map, int from, int to, T value) {
    for (int i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        map.put(i, value);
    }
}
public static long execute(Runnable... runnables) {
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicLong duration = new AtomicLong();
    for (Runnable runnable : runnables) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                    duration.accumulateAndGet(elapsed, Math::max);
                }
            });
        thread.start();
        threads.add(thread);
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return duration.get();
}
```